# How to override default logging information in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, asp.net-core, .net-core

When I start default ASP.NET Core application I got the following lines in console:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Where I can change this logs?

Comment: I found several articles about `IApplicationLifetime` and `IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted` but it doesn't work anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines are not logged, instead they are printed to the console. What is causing this output is the [`WebHost.Run()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/941a6ebb7fef22e72e84ee507d6c434e7760f258/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostExtensions.cs#L56) which is the default way to start your application. Or in particular, the internal [`RunAsync()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostExtensions.cs#L86) which sets everything up.

You cannot change the output without writing that code yourself.